# The AbstractArchiveTask.destinationDir property has been deprecated. Gradle in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

I was creating APK for my flutter project so I followed the below steps to generate a signed APK

**Tools -> Flutter -> Open for editing in android studio**

Then opened the model in a new window

I got the Gradle sync failed error, After my further investigation I run the command **gradlew --warning-mode all** in the terminal & I got the below message from gradle

**The AbstractArchiveTask.destinationDir property has been deprecated. This is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 7.0. Please use the destinationDirectory property instead.**

Since I am new to flutter & always scared of Gradle failing, I am not sure how to fix this issue & set the destination directory

Or if you know how to create APK from the flutter project do let me know if I am doing anything wrong to generate APK

Comment: I get the same issue. Does anyone has any solution? I have posted a question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72055485/deprecation-warning-in-gradle-in-android-studio-in-flutter-project

Answer (score 0):

Gradle sync failed error is not any error in flutter.

> to build apk in flutter first of all you run `flutter clean` command
> then run `flutter pub get` command

> after then you run `flutter build apk` command to build apk

also if you use Android Studio then you can build apk without command using

in Android Studio in top menu **Build => Flutter => Build APK** and click on Build APK
it will make apk for you

Comment: Thanks @Khunt arpit , i tried Build => Flutter => Build APK but it didn't asked me the keystore details to generate release APK. do you know how to do that?

Comment: import android folder of your project in Android Studio IDE and install gradle and then generate signed apk

Comment: sorry for the late reply, can you explain to me the steps to generate a signed APK?